# changing the value using javascript or jquery..is it even possible?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I am looking for a way to change the value what I passed to function once a button is pressed

```
<span id="showHidden" style=" margin-left:726px; position:relative; top:40;">
        <input type="image" id="btnShowHidden" src/images/hide.gif" onclick="showHiddenRecords(1);" />
        </span>
```

As you see in showHiddenRecords, its passing a value of 1. What I want is to toggle these value every time a user clicks the image. so if its one it will change to zero and if its zero it will chnage back to one. Is this possible? how?

e.g;
showHiddenRecords(1)
showHiddenRecords(0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#btnShowHidden").click(function() {
    this.value = this.value == "1" ? "0" : "1";
  });
});
```

Then you can remove the in-line functions all-together.

If you want to toggle something *else*, you can use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#btnShowHidden").toggle(function() {
    showHiddenRecords(1);
  }, function() {
    showHiddenRecords(0);
  });
});
```

Comment: Nick, I think you need a ? where you have a :

Comment: I am confused..how will it pass the value to the function?

Comment: @user295189 - What is the function doing? The second version will run your literal function, but it would be easier if we understood what the function was doing.

Comment: the function is just taking 1 or 0 and sending it to a php post for a query

Comment: @user295189 - Did you try the second version, removing the in-line `onclick`?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `onclick="showHiddenRecords(1);"` from the `input` tag, then add in this jQuery in `$(document).ready()`;:

```
$("#btnShowHidden").toggle(function(){showHiddenRecords(1);},function(){showHiddenRecords(0);});
```

This uses [jQuery's toggle function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to do things on alternate clicks

Comment: @user295189 that's strange. you've got it inside $(document).ready(function(){ //put code here}); ? What browser are you using? what happens if you replace the showHiddenRecord functions with alerts?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have some hidden records on page?

In jQuery you can use the toggle function to handle this...

```
<div></div>
<div class="hiddenrecord"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="hiddenrecord"></div>
<div class="hiddenrecord"></div>

<span id="showHidden" style=" margin-left:726px; position:relative; top:40;">
        <input type="image" id="btnShowHidden" src/images/hide.gif" onclick="$('.hiddenrecord').toggle();" />
</span>
```